# Open Instagram App from Android with Gallery for selection

Tags: android, android-studio, instagram, instagram-api

I am currently using this code to send an image to Instagram from Android.
It is just sending one image.

What I want to achieve is save multiple image in Gallery and instead of opening 1 image. Just open the post with the gallery option where user can select multiple images.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");

Uri uri = Uri.parse(mediaPath.getString(0));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

[image: Current Implementation]

[image: Required]

Thanks

Comment: If you want to send multiple things, try `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. However, it is possible that Instagram does not support this. If so, you would need to see if Instagram offers some other API that offers what you seek.

Comment: I've already tried `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` and it works for adding the images to the story and not for the feed. I've tried many other things but all ends on Screen 1. The other view is from a different app and they are able to do this somehow.

Comment: You will need to look to see if Instagram offers some other API that offers what you seek, then.